# Facebook login redirect URL set state pass parameter in redirect uri

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

how can i set state to redirect URL

i have to pass register.php?csrf=abc;

```
$redirect_uri=$protocol.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/facebook/register.php";
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_uri);
$permissions = array(
  'email',    
  'public_profile'
  ); 
   $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($permissions);
    $loginUrl=$loginUrl."&auth_type=rerequest";
     header('Location: '.$loginUrl); exit;
```